# Loading Keras model with custom layer that takes in parameters

Tags: keras, padding

I am using a custom reflection padding layer that I found in another question -

```
class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), **kwargs):
    self.padding = tuple(padding)
    self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4)]
    super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], input_shape[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], input_shape[3])

def call(self, input_tensor, mask=None):
    padding_width, padding_height = self.padding
    return pad(input_tensor, [[0,0], [padding_height, padding_height], [padding_width, padding_width], [0,0] ], 'REFLECT')
```

It works fine during training. The problem is my model uses both (1,1) size padding and (2,2). When I load the model to use it, the **init** function initializes the padding to (1,1) even if the saved model was using (2,2), which gives the wrong output shape for the next layer and the model can't be loaded.

Edit: this is a working way that loads correctly (as long as you add "pad" as a custom object when loading the model). I still would like to find a way to load my already trained model though because I spent days training it.

```
from tensorflow import pad
def reflectPad(inp, p):
    return Lambda(lambda x: pad(x, [[0, 0], [p, p], [p, p], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT'))(inp)
```

Comment: in method load_model() there is a argument called custom_objects. You can read about it and check if it can work for you.

Comment: I am using custom_objects already to load the layer, the problem is it doesn't seem to remember the padding size for each custom layer, it just uses the default (1,1) everywhere it sees the layer

Comment: Your layer did not implement the method get_config(), where you should have saved this information so its part of the model. You should implement this